Sequence involving plane curves is exact
I'm reading through Andreas Gathmann's Algebraic Curves and there is this affirmative on Proposition 2.10 at page 14:
Let $P\in\mathbb{A}^2$, and $F, G, H$ curves (or polynomials). If $F$ and $G$ have no common components through $P$, then there is an exact sequence
$$
0 \rightarrow \dfrac{\mathcal{O}_P}{\langle F,H\rangle} \overset{G}{\rightarrow} \dfrac{\mathcal{O_P}}{\langle F, GH\rangle} \overset{\pi}{\rightarrow} \dfrac{\mathcal{O_P}}{\langle F,G\rangle}\rightarrow 0
$$
where $\pi$ is the natural quotient map, $G$ is the multiplication by the polynomial $G$.
Now, the textbook states that is should be trivial to see that the maps G and $\pi$ verify
$$
im \,\, G = ker \,\,\pi
$$
but I'm only able to show that $im \,\, G \subset \ker \,\,\pi$. I'm trying to pick representants on each quotient but to no avail.
Would someone give me a hand, please? Thanks in advance.
